# An idiom (or perhaps analogy -- metaphor/simile/etc) related to a lack of interest

Tags: idiom-requests

I am writing a story about a character (Atsushi) meeting his partner. The first time he comes across a particular character (Wyatt) is when Wyatt offers him a new job after being fired for the nth time. (He gets fired a lot because his mother is a temperamental goddess and frequently tracks him down at his workplace) However, Atsushi has no interest in Wyatt or the job offer whatsoever. I could have sworn there was an idiom or common analogy to express just how uninterested he is.

The actual text I have written is:

> He shrugged his shoulders as he left the room and said, 'I guess the
> only solution is to work for–'
>
> 'How about me?' A man that looked much
> younger than Atsushi smiled at him and then winked. He was very buff
> looking, especially for a vampire (a species not known for having
> visible musculature), his skin looked like it was covered in ash, and
> his hair the color of iron. 'I can guarantee I won't fire you no
> matter how many times this lovely lady shows up at the office.'
>
> Atsushi just walked past him, refusing to give him the time of day. He
> had no more interest in the man (who in all actuality was probably a
> scammer) than he would in say – **[insert idiom here]**. 'Let's go
> Mother.'

Comment: I don’t give a …….

Comment: I think you're confusing disinterested and uninterested. The former means unbiased.

Comment: There is no single idiom that is used to express a general feeling. Authors use their imagination.

Comment: I've found a creative (not idiomatic) simile: 'He's about as interested in teaching the material as a gopher is in sunbathing.'

Comment: Thank you Stuart for correcting my word choice! I don't use either word very often, as you can see.  And haha Edwin! Now I want to see a sunbathing gopher!

Comment: This will end is an list of opinions.

Answer (score 1):

You might use your own imagination, some people do, and from the attempts that have been collected in this source, [*A list of French Similes*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/316992),  they can sometimes come up with ideas that are in my opinion worth considering.

- (one would) for a street-sprinkler in Venice, (one would) for a washing machine in a nudist colony, (one would) for a Florida newspaper in California,

*Example*

- a tie to wear with his T-shirts

Comment: I'm in love with the washing machine in a nudist colony!   Thanks for the link! That was an interesting read!